# Is it possible send a specified file (input type=file)?

Tags: html

I need to upload a file repeatedly by browser (automatic) and refresh time ask me for confirm.

How can i to POST form with a specified file?

Sorry my english

Comment: please share some code first.

Comment: Imagine if a browser could automatically access your filesystem and send fules to the server, i don't want to do that, trust me

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you make available what you already tried, then we know where you are getting stuck.

Basically if you need to upload a file to a remote server you will need a dynamic language like PHP, Python, etc.

You can't send files to a remote server using plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons HTML itself won't let you send files to a remote webserver via `<form>` automatically.

For that feature you would have to have your webserver handle the form via a special file like for example `<form action="exampleFormHandler.php" method="post">`.

Placed at your webserver, this form-handling file would have to provide the sending of that very file then.